# \savetrees and authors block in IEEE trans

Tags: ieeetran, author, savetrees

So I have this savetrees package and I want to add two authors with two large affiliations. I use the author block environment but everything is shifted to the right sided of the page and things do not appear as they should. [image: This is with the savetrees subtle package added.]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{ \IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and

\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, it's too hard to provide you an answer with only an image. So could you show us your snippet in the form of a MWE?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the source of the problem does not lie within savetrees itself but rather the microtype package, which savetrees loads.  I assume you observe the same problem if you replace

```
 \usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
```

with

```
 \usepackage[letterspace=25,tracking=all]{microtype}
```

As a workaround, try loading savetrees with

```
 \usepackage[subtle,tracking=normal]{savetrees}
```

or

```
\usepackage[moderate,tracking=normal]{savetrees}
```

or

```
\usepackage[extreme,tracking=normal]{savetrees}
```

depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved me hour!